# Best optimization for MySQL query with many JOINS

Tags: mysql

I developing a classifieds website with around 200k ads.
When the user visit an specific category I run this query, many many times.

```
# Time: 171129 21:04:05
# User@Host: erich33_bache4[erich33_bache4] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 11596  Schema: erich33_bache3  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.629711  Lock_time: 0.000252  Rows_sent: 75  Rows_examined: 12717
use erich33_bache3;
SET timestamp=1512007445;
SELECT `category`.`id` as `category_id`, `category`.`subcat` as `category_name`, `category`.`desc` as `category_desc`, `category`.`name` as `category_pretty_name`, `ads`.`id`, `ads`.`header`, `ads`.`price`, `ads`.`oldprice`, `ads`.`sellfast`, `ads`.`hash`, `ads`.`foto1`, `ads`.`foto2`, `ads`.`foto3`, `ads`.`foto4`, `ads`.`foto5`, `ads`.`user_id`, SUBSTR(ads.body, 1, 160) as body, `ads`.`subcat_id`, `ads`.`updated`, `ads`.`created`, `ads`.`email`, `ads`.`name`, `ads`.`phone`, `ads`.`hits`, `ads`.`hidden`, `promo`.`promotype` as `promo_type`, `provinces`.`prov_name`, `supercategory`.`name` as `supercategory_name`, `supercategory`.`id` as `supercategory_id`
FROM `ads`
JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id` = `ads`.`subcat_id`
JOIN `supercategory` ON `supercategory`.`id` = `category`.`cat`
JOIN `provinces` ON `provinces`.`id` = `ads`.`province_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `promo` ON `promo`.`ads_id` = `ads`.`id`
WHERE `ads`.`subcat_id` = '54'
AND `recycle_bin` != 1
AND `hidden` =0
ORDER BY `promo_type` DESC, `updated` DESC
LIMIT 75;
```

My question is, as a NO expertise in MySQL, How do I optimize the foreign tables for a Better `Query_time: 0.629711`

This is the EXPLAIN result. I'm new and noob to MySQL But I thinks, there could be some optimizations.

[image: EXPLAIN QUERY]

Comment: Show your table structures, show what indexes you have on the tables, show an EXPLAIN for the query

Comment: First thing to do is look at *Indexes* - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I guess you have a key on promo_type, updated, hidden and recycle_bin fields?!
may even be one key

Comment: you can also consider caching the query response for each `subcat_id`

Comment: The caching is a good idea but, sometimes I pass GET parameters for a filter search

Comment: Wow, I figure now! in the `promo` table I haven't set promotype as an index, that could be?